# accordion control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have accordion control and having set of link button controls inside accordion control. I use the following code.

```
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" Class="accordion" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"  
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"  
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent" runat="server" Width="248px">
    <Panes>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
            <Header>Registration</Header>
            <Content>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="CandidateRegistration" CssClass="linkButton" 
                    runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                    OnClick="candidatesRegistration_Click" 
                    Text="Candidates Registered"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="registrationByRqp" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="registrationByRqp_Click" 
                    Text="Registered Through RQP"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="registrationByUi" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="registrationByUi_Click" 
                    Text="Registered Through UI"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="avgRegistration" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="avgRegistration_Click" 
                    Text="Average Registration"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="jobsRegistered" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="jobsRegistered_Click" 
                    Text="Jobs registered"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="unregistered" ForeColor="Black" 
                    runat="server" Text="Unregistered Candidate" 
                    OnClick="unregistered_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
            <Header>Job Alerts</Header>
            <Content>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="jobAlert" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                    OnClick="jobAlert_Click">Job Alert</asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="minScoreAlerts" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="minScoreAlerts_Click">
                    Minimum score of job alerts</asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="maxScoreAlerts" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="maxScoreAlerts_Click">
                    Maximum score of job alerts</asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="avgScoreJobAlerts" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="avgScoreJobAlerts_Click">
                    Average score of daily alerts</asp:LinkButton><br />
            </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane4" runat="server">
            <Header>Analysis</Header> 
            <Content>
                <asp:LinkButton  ID="searchpeakTime" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="searchpeakTime_Click">
                    Search peak time</asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="userActivityReport" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="userActivityReport_Click">
                    User Activity Report</asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="operationalusage" runat="server" 
                    ForeColor="Black" OnClick="operationalusage_Click">
                    Operational Usage</asp:LinkButton>
            </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server">
            <Header>Overview</Header> 
            <Content>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Overview" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" 
                    OnClick="Overview_Click" >Overview</asp:LinkButton><br />
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</asp:Accordion>&nbsp; &nbsp;<br />
```

.Its works properly . But when i click the the link button in the second or third accordion pane the page will be redirected but the visibility return to accordionpane1. I want which link button i click meaks the corresponded accordion pane will be visible and not the first . Can anyone able help for that?
Thankx in advance......

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "AutoSize="Fill"" property to achieve that. Have look at this [question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1255780.aspx), it will solve your problem.